# Renaming multiple file names

Tags: batch-file

I would like to ask how will identify string length of a file name

Here it how it goes

I have several file w/c have the file names listed below

557531_S_10CG_Layout-1

557531_S_10CG_Layout-2

557531_S_10CG_Layout-3

and the output must be

557531_S_1

557531_S_2

557531_S_3

the string *10CG_Layout-* should have been deleted. but the code should identify from the start w/c  is the *557531_S* and the last w/c is the number.

here's my code

```
::Change the *.pdf*
for %%f in (*.pdf*) do call :rename "%%f"

goto :eof

:rename
set var=%~n1
set var1=%~x1
::Change the 10 (start) and -1 (end)
ren %1 %var:~0,10%%var1%
```

but the output is just

**557531_S_**

please advise

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (*_*_*_*-*.pdf) Do Call :Sub "%%A"
Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "_=%~1"
Set "i=1"
Set "_%i%=%_:_="&Set/A i+=1&Set "_!i!=%"
Echo=Ren "%_%" "%_1%_%_2%_!_%i%:*-=!"
GoTo :EOF
```

If the output looks okay then you can remove `Echo=` from line `11` before removing line `4`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

::Change the *.pdf*
for %%f in (%sourcedir%\*.pdf*) do call :chgname "%%f"

goto :eof

:chgname
set var=%~n1
set var1=%~x1
::Change the 10 (start) and -1 (end)
ECHO ren %1 %var:~0,9%%var:~-1%%var1%
:: another method
set var=%~nx1

ECHO ren %1 "%var:10CG_Layout-=%"


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

I've changed the subroutine name deliberately because `rename` is a synonym of `ren`.

Your method was using the `1` from `10CG_Layout-` not the last character of the name as you appear to require. The output would be 10 characters, not 9 as you report. The changes appear obvious, but `-1` means `the last character`.

The formula for the second method is "%name:*string*=*replacementstring*%"

Comment: HI Magoo thanks for this helpful idea

but the **10CG_Layout-1** is dynamic or varying 

example 

I also have the stocks listed below

14CM_Layout-

100PM_Layout-

100PG_Layout-

14CUV1S_Layout-

4WVUV_Layout-

and so on

that is why im detecting the starting and ending